# Why did James Moriarty decide to end it this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, sherlock

At the end of [*Sherlock*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1475582/) S02E03 it simply doesn't make sense for me that James Moriarty killed himself. I mean, for me there is nothing greater than life, so why would he kill himself?

I understand that James Moriarty may be brilliant and *insane*, but insanity doesn't seem like a valid enough reason to commit suicide. Especially if Moriarty was so smart, couldn't he guess that it might be possible for Sherlock to fake his own death after all, and hence have the ultimate last laugh?

(I've only watched up to the first episode in season 3 and I hope the answer doesn't lie in the second or the third episode of season 3.)

Comment: Are you referring to the BBC Sherlock? If yes, I think you haven't watched Season 3 yet :/

Comment: Why do ask ask? Do you miss him?

Comment: *"I mean, there is nothing greater than life"* - Yes, there is, *winning against Sherlock Holmes*!

Comment: While maybe phrased a bit subjectively, this isn't such a bad question at all.

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan Is season 3 really required to understand *Moriarty*'s motivation to kill himself (or does he return in season 3)? If yes, you might want to post an additional answer, as I for myself cannot speak of season 3 (yet still think to have understood *Moriarty* well enough).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - At the end of season 3 something Moriarty related happens. But we'll have to wait until season 4 to know what exactly it means. Depending on how the writers resolve the cliffhanger, it could have an impact on how to answer this question.

Comment: @Oliver_C So you mean there's a chance *Meat Trademark*'s answer might not be as 100% correct as it seems?

Comment: @Oliver_C *"Depending on how the writers resolve the cliffhanger, it could have an impact on how to answer this question."* - Still they have to have thought *something* at the end of season 2. When everybody else thought he was dead, there still has to be a reason why he killed himself, no matter if two years later everything is moot anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - An answer about _X_ can change when _X_ turns out not be what we thought it was (I'm trying to avoid spoilers).

Comment: @Oliver_C If you want to wait another year to give an answer, then that is your decision. I try to make the best out of the things given. And saying the question is irrelevant as we don't know if he's dead or not is not an option for me. If the whole episode/season was a dream by some interdimensional alien, we're not bound to any physical laws of life and death anyway, but ok. When new information arrives, an answer can always be adapted, changed or just left for reference purposes. (Neither can I understand *Keen*'s decision to delete his correct answer, but to each his own.)

Comment: I, of course, think my answer is correct, but acknowledge that it's not 100% proven yet. I personally never believed Moriarty actually killed himself. And it could be a way easier explanation (blocked barrel gun, a blank, a squib and a blood-pack) than Sherlock's finely orchestrated charade. And for the record I *upvoted* Keen's answer for the logic of the action whether or not it is "true." The motivation remains solid. Even if he's alive he faked it for {INSERT REASON}. I vote @Keen undelete his answer.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Not sure why you think I said `this question is irrelevant`. - Of course one give an answer based on current information, all I'm saying is that the answer _might_ change depending on what is revealed in season 4.

Comment: @Oliver_C *"Not sure why you think I said"* - Not sure why you think I think you said, but nevermind. *"all I'm saying is that the answer might change depending on what is revealed in season 4."* - Indeed.

Comment: The real question is how did Sherlock know Moriarty would kill himself? He wouldn't be able to fake his death if Moriarty witnesses it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is in **season three**:

> **He didn't kill himself.**
>  He returns at the end of episode 3, season 3.

Sorry for the spoiler, but watch the show, right?

The question and one answer were both posted by people who admitted they hadn't watched season three. Careful what you ask as the guidelines warn that these sites are spoiler-prone.

**EDIT :**

I'm not claiming my answer is 100% true (Moffat is a clever son-of-a-gun), but this sheds light on the possible "reality" of the situation.

After a video signal takes over London's screens, we have to question what we thought we knew.

> A version of Moriarty's face reciting "Did you miss me?" in a variation of vocal tones and speeds. [image: miss me]

And after the credits is a more **compelling** conclusion:

> A non .gif or Max-Headroomy glimpse that he's back: a clear image of Moriarty looking directly into the camera asking "Miss me?" [image]

I'd be remiss and regretful if I didn't also acknowledge the brilliant use of the false ending. Maudlin music, fading to black, the drums for the end-titles kick in and **TV static** and we're back in the show for a mad twist. BRILLIANT! I know Monty Python was spot-on with this misdirection, but don't remember a dramatic show using this device. (Could be a question on its own?)

Comment: No need to put the whole answer in spoiler block, only the actual spoilers. Strange that they don't seem to work, though. And +1 for the seemingly correct answer (if I am to trust what you say), but I still hate it when a very simple answer (no matter if correct) destroys my efforts, but this isn't your fault, anyway. ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, but it is the correct syntax, I think.

Comment: Well, it should still work (and might be a valid case, since the OP hasn't seen it yet, even if I'm generally an opponent of spoiler blocks anyway).

Comment: It's not yet clear what that cliffhanger really means. Your conclusion is indeed the most obvious one, but whether it's the right one remains to be seen.

Comment: The very last shot was him, not just a .gif or whatever. Of course, it could be a prerecorded thing (like Sherlock's from the first episode of the season), but if he had the foresight to do that, he probably had the foresight to fake his death. We'll see. Moffat (as a show-runner) has proven on Doctor Who he likes to plan things WAAAY in advance... Plus, Moriarty didn't need all the planning Sherlock did. Mostly just a squib and blood-pack. Plus, lends more meaning to Moriarty listening to "Stayin' Alive" at the scene's beginning.

Comment: I think your large excuse paragraph at the end isn't really neccessary. Nobody has mistaken your answer for anything else than a valid answer. If anyone decides to delete their answers, then that is entirely their decision. In fact that odd comment at the end degrades it a bit and would been better fit as an actual comment. Yet the spoiler picture is apreciated and if, like *Oliver_C* says, it isn't entirely clear if he survived or not, you might want to clarify that in the answer instead of giving excuses for things that don't need an excuse at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson And another pass at it... Tell Rau I said thanks.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - The question is, was that clip _after_ the credits "in-universe" or a breaking of the 4th wall. Moffat [implies](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/tv/s129/sherlock/news/a549261/sherlock-steven-moffat-explains-moriarty-post-credits-scene.html) the latter, but he also says _"[Moriarty] was definitely dead! You can't fake shooting yourself in the face - part of his head came off."_ - What mind games are you playing, Mr. Moffat?

Comment: Please cite the reference for that, also we didn't actually see "part of his head (come) off." And I'd suggest that he's the show-runner for Doctor Who and uses the mantra "The Doctor Lies." http://postimg.org/image/8kbgrl3i7/   http://tinypic.com/r/1zbyq76/8

Comment: I meant to mention (along with the pics) that he put the gun in his mouth, as opposed to "shooting yourself[himself] in the face" according to Moffat (citation needed.)

Comment: @MeatTrademark - I did source it with a link (click the word `implies`). - At last years ComicCon Moffat [said](http://geek-news.mtv.com/2013/07/18/sdcc-2013-sherlock-panel/): _He shot himself in the face, what more do you want? Do you think they were up on that rooftop to fake suicide each other?_ - And at a Q&A after a preview screening of 'The Empty Hearse' he [said](http://www.empireonline.com/empireblogs/small-screen/post/p1439): _They did not fake suicide at each other. Imagine how stupid you’d feel if you bumped into each other afterwards._ - But yeah, I've learned not to trust Moffat.

Comment: So sorry. I missed the text was blue. Really very sorry. HAL-9000 classic HUMAN ERROR scenario. Still, yeah. I have no reason to trust Moffat. Still, DAMN! Now I'm doubting this, which is exactly what Moffat wants. GRRRR! POOH! UGH. Sooo many months before more Doctor Who and more months before more Sherlock. Moffat is one of the most hated of the people I love. Dick! :)

Comment: Fourth season disagrees.

Answer (score 10):

In light of *Meat Trademark*'s answer the following discussion about *Moriarty*'s motivations *might* be moot, but I'll still stand by this answer in order to give a valid explanation in light of the existing 3 seasons, disregarding any future revelations.

---

The main point is indeed his insanity. First of all, insanity can be a reason for pretty much anything, especially suicide. But to be more specific, *Moriarty*'s ultimate goal was to win against *Sherlock* in a battle of wits. As *Keen* says in his answer, *Sherlock* reasons about the possibility for *Moriarty* to call back the assassins and thus for *Sherlock* to not have to kill himself. So as long as *Moriarty* lived, *Sherlock* wasn't broken yet. So *Moriarty* leaves him with (supposedly) no options left when he kills himself, thinking that he has finally defeated him mentally.

And in fact *Moriarty*'s brilliance *was* his insanity, or to be exact, his judgement of his brilliance to be more important than his life. For him there *was* something *"greater than life"*, it was to win against *Sherlock Holmes*. There are enough examples, be it in history or the movies, of people sacrificing themselves for (what they think to be) higher ideals that are more important than their own lives, and *James Moriarty* is one of those.

So the question is not if *we* would do the same or what *we* regard highest in the world, but if we can understand why *he* did so given his portrayal throughout the show, and for me this was a perfect ending for him, nobly sacrificing himself for the ultimate win (the biggest problem I would have with doing so was the inability to make sure that I was successful at all, which unfortunately for *Moriarty*, was not the case).

---

As to the updated question, *Moriarty* might have been very smart, but he also was extremely arrogant in his believes that noone, not even the great *Sherlock Holmes* could beat him in a battle of wits. When he killed himself he actually thought that he had considered (and prevented) each and every possibility for *Sherlock* to solve this *final problem*. In retrospecitive one could say it was a stupid idea to kill himself without being sure that *Sherlock* couldn't survive, but *Moriarty* really *was* 100% sure, blinded by his arrogance and superior intellect and his insane will (and confidence) to prevail over *Sherlock*.

Comment: If Moriarty was so smart, couldn't he guess that it might be possible for Sherlock to fake his own death, and hence have the ultimate last laugh?

Comment: @Graviton Smart enough maybe, but also arrogant enough to not consider *Sherlock* having another ingenious plan up his sleeve. He really thought he'd considered every possibility.

Comment: @Graviton Ok, updated the answer.

Comment: In my opinion killing is what you do when you are _at the end of your wits_. It's a cheat. It's like removing your king from the chess board and announcing yourself the winner of the game because your opponent can now no longer checkmate you. - Why didn't Moriarty just kill Sherlock to win? Because it wouldn't be a _battle of wits_ then.

Comment: @Oliver_C That is indeed a very interesting take and might be worth an answer on its own (just ignore the fact that the actual answer is much simpler, a proper character analysis can beat a damn spoiler! ;-)).